# "And" conjuction-reduction

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

According to this sentence:

> A projector moves the film forward at 24 frames per second so that our eyes register moving images and {**not still ones**}.

I am not sure whether it "doesn't register non-moving images" or "register non-moving images". And *still* usage doesn't grasp it.

And (conjuction) have been made reduction, Can you please make a full sentence - without reduction ?

Comment: What's the exact question, here?  The usage of *still*?

Comment: What bearing does the title of this question have on the body of the question? (And, to echo another comment, what is the actual question?)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only plausible way to understand this sentence is:

> A projector moves the film forward at 24 frames per second so that our eyes register moving images and don't register still ones.

That said this is technically false since as I see it, your eyes actually "register" still images (shown at the speed of 24 fps) but your brain puts them together.

Answer (score -1):

> *A projector moves the film forward at 24 frames per second so that our eyes register moving images **and not still ones**.*

The phrase is describing the illusion of film.  Even though a person might *know* that a film is a sequence of frames *(still images)* played in succession, the speed of that playback *(24 frames per second)* is enough to fool our eyes/brains into believing that the subject of the film is moving.